# /etc/environment in Linux EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wanted to set Path for JAVA_HOME for systemwide (all users) in in linux EC2 machine so i tried below

```
 vi /etc/environment
 JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_221
 PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

When i logout and logged in again i am unable to run any commands in the linux machine and now only Java command is working now.

Below are the message i am getting.How to correct this?

```
 If you need a GUI type startx at the prompt. -bash: id: command not found
 -bash: id: command not found
 -bash: id: command not found
 -bash: tty: command not found
 -bash: ls: command not found
 /usr/libexec/grepconf.sh: line 5: grep: command not found
 -bash: TMOUT: readonly variable
 -bash: expor: command not found

 [user1@XXXXX ~]$ java -version
 java version "1.8.0_221"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
 [user1@XXXXX ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
 /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_221

 [user1@XXXXX ~]$ cat /etc/environment
 -bash: cat: command not found
 [user1@XXXXX ~]$
```

I am not able to run any Linux command.

Comment: Kindly let me know if this and stackoverflow.com/questions/60025206/… are working for you. Leave me a comment if you need help

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have overwriten or omitted the base system path. Try this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_221" 
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```